# SAPUI5 GridList Component Grouping Issue

Tags: sapui5

I would like to use grouping feature for the GridList component. But when I used to grouping feature, the list items can not show separate rows. The all items show in inline position. I'm using the same coding just like in the [this](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.GridList/sample/sap.f.sample.GridListBoxContainerGrouping) url

Here is the screenshow of my view https://ibb.co/M90Pb5T

Here is my coding:

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:grid="sap.ui.layout.cssgrid"
xmlns:f="sap.f" controllerName="SapUI5Tutorial.RootApp">
<Panel>
    <content>
        <f:GridList items="{
                    path: '/DataList',
                    sorter: {
                        path: 'groupTitle',
                        group: true
                    }
                }">
            <f:customLayout>
                <grid:GridBoxLayout boxWidth="15rem"/>
            </f:customLayout>
            <f:GridListItem>
                <VBox >
                    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
                        <layoutData>
                            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" shrinkFactor="0" />
                        </layoutData>
                        <Title text="{title}" wrapping="true" />
                        <Label text="{subtitle}" wrapping="true" />
                    </VBox>
                </VBox>
            </f:GridListItem>
        </f:GridList>
    </content>
</Panel>
```

Here is the controller.js (Init function)

```
var data = [
    { title: "Grid item title 1", subtitle: "Subtitle 1", groupTitle: "Group A" },
    { title: "Grid item title 2", subtitle: "Subtitle 2", groupTitle: "Group A" },
    { title: "Grid item title 3", subtitle: "Subtitle 3", groupTitle: "Group A" },
    { title: "Grid item title 10", subtitle: "Subtitle 10", groupTitle: "Group B" },
    { title: "Grid item title 11", subtitle: "Subtitle 11", groupTitle: "Group B" },
    { title: "Grid item title 12", subtitle: "Subtitle 12", groupTitle: "Group B" },
  ];
  oModel.setProperty("/DataList", data);
```

**Where am I doing mistake?**

Please let me know about this issue. I would like to see separate row for the GroupHeaderListItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have research a little bit on the web and I've resolved the issue by adding `sap.f` library to `index.html` file.

Here is the code:

```
<script id ="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src = "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-theme = "sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-libs = "sap.m,sap.tnt,sap.f,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3"
  data-sap-ui-bindingsyntax = "complex"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion = "edge"
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots = '{ "SapUI5Tutorial": "./" }'></script>
```